# TripleHead2Go - did you use it with PC to HDMI TV connections

Tags: hdmi, tv

Anyone connected HDMI cables to this box: [Matrox TripleHead2Go](http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/gxm/th2go/) ? And if yes what adapter did you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on which model of the TripleHead2Go you get.  If you get the "Digital Edition" (Part: T2G-D3D-IF), then you need a 3rd party DVI->HDMI adapter.

You can get these types of adapters, and cables from places like NewEgg or StarTech.

[Here's a link to a 6' cable from StartTech](http://www.startech.com/Cables/Audio-Video/HDMI/6ft-HDMI-to-DVI-Digital-Video-Cable~HDMIDVIMM6) for reference.

If you are using the TripleHead2Go DP (DisplayPort) Edition (Part: T2G-DP-MIF), you'll need a 3rd-party DP->HDMI converter.

[Here's one from StarTech](http://www.startech.com/AV/Displayport-Converters/DisplayPort-to-HDMI-Cable-Adapter-Converter~DP2HDMI2) for reference.

**Edit (more info):**

DVI and HDMI are electrically compatible, so a properly wired cable/adapter shouldn't (be able to) cause any problems.  I use multiple DVI->HDMI (passive) cables to drive my TV and monitors, and they work perfectly fine.

I haven't used a TripleHead2Go DP version, but as long as it's "Dual-Mode" DisplayPort (AKA "DP++", which it *probably* is) then a passive adapter to convert to (single-link) HDMI/DVI or Analog is easy, as DP++ had lines in it to specifically allow this.

If it's Just DP (no "++") then you'd need an active (powered) adapter that can pump up the DP signal strength to support HDMI or DVI.  [See here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayPort#Compatibility_with_HDMI.2FDVI).

Personally, if I want HDMI, and don't have any DP displays, I'd get the "Digital Edition" and go DVI->HDMI using passive adapters.

Comment: I have tried these types of cables in past but they fried the TV and the graphics card. Since than I always use scaler for HDMI. Did you actually get this to work with the cable you posted?

Comment: @Mat Banik - Added some more info for you.